# How to add rows with missing dates in correct order of a dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

I have a DataFrame with column 'Date' (format e.g. 2020-06-26). Type of this column is `str`. This column is sorted in descending order: 2020-06-26, 2020-06-25, 2020-06-24...The other column 'Reviews' is made of text. There are duplicate dates, so the dateframe can have **multiple reviews** on a given date or **no reviews** on another date. I wrote a code to find which dates are missing. I have a list (`insert_dates`) with 3 missing dates in format `%Y-%m-%d`.

When I try to append these 3 dates to my dataframe `df` nothing changes, Len(df) remains the same. Here's what I simply did:

```
row = pd.Series([insert_dates[0],None], index=['Date', 'Review'])
row1 = pd.Series([insert_dates[1],None], index=['Date', 'Review'])
row2 = pd.Series([insert_dates[2],None], index=['Date', 'Review'])
df.append(row, ignore_index=True)
df.append(row1, ignore_index=True)
df.append(row2, ignore_index=True)
df.head()
```

What should I do?

Comment: `append` is not an in-place operation. Try `df = df.append(...)`

Comment: thanks that worked for appending rows and changing len(df). But my next problem is how to order these rows in descending order of date. e.g one of missing dates of `insert_dates` is 2020-06-21. How can I place this row right after last df['Date'] = 2020-06-22 (there are many rows with 2020-06-22) ?

Comment: If your date format is `YYYY-MM-DD`, you can do `df.sort_values(by='Date', ascending=False)`.

Comment: I tried that and last 3 values are not those from ``insert_dates`` anymore, which is good. However, all indices are now out of order and randomly/wrongly placed. I tried ``df.reset_index(inplace=True)`` but it is not fixed. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

1. `append` is not an in-place operation.
2. You can sort the dates directly with `sort_values` if your date format is `YYYY-MM-DD`. For cases such as day-first dates, you should use `pd.to_datetime` before sorting.

```py
df = df.append([row, row1, row2], ignore_index=True)
df = df.sort_values(by='Date', ascending=False)
```

Comment: df = df.sort_values(by='Date', ascending=False) does not work, it is changing all index randomly. Not following the correct sorting by date order. For example first 50 rows are all dated 2020-06-25 (they should not change after adding those 3 new dates bc all new dates are after 2020-06-25). But index for these rows appear random as 0, 10, 1, 18, 17... any thoughts?

Comment: Try `df.reset_index(drop=True)`. Also can you please edit your question to add example data and the desired output?

Comment: since there are hundreds of 'Reviews' for one single date, when using `df = df.sort_values(by='Date', ascending=False)` all rows with same date are randomly sorted. Each time I run the program there is a **different index order** for 'Reviews' with **same date**. Is there a way of keeping the default order for each 'Date' ?